# How do I get the model names in a type form? (Prisma)

Tags: prisma

Is there a type exported from Prisma that gives me the models as types? For example, If I have the following models:

```
model Config {
  ...
}
model User {
  ...
}
model Server {
  ...
}
```

Is there a type that is: `'Config' | 'User' | 'Server'` If not, how can I create one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `Prisma.ModelName` is what you are looking for:

```
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

// This is what you need probably:
Prisma.ModelName
```

All the types are contained in the `node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts` file, so if you need some type you can just look into this file and try to find, maybe it is there.